# What does "endurance athlete" mean?

Tags: meaning

"ActiVenam Energy Charge is high performance pre-workout supplement designed for endurance athletes."
I googled it but I could find any definition for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Athlete* here is used in the American sense, referring to any person who trains for skill and strength in physical sports or exercise— *athletics* in the American sense. (This contrasts with British usage, where *athletics* refers to the running, jumping, and hurtling sports which Americans know as *track and field*.)

Thus, an *endurance athlete* is someone who trains for *endurance sports*. Segen's Medical Dictionary via TFD [defines it as](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Endurance+Sport)

> A sports activity by individual—i.e., non team—athletes in which key muscles are exercised at submaximal intensity for prolonged periods of time
>   *Examples* Swimming, wrestling, weightlifting, cycling, cross-country skiing, race walking

In common usage, *endurance sports* tends to emphasize sports and events where conditioning is a primary factor in competitiveness, over skill or strength, and does include some sports where competitors are organized and cooperate as teams (e.g. competitive road bicycle racing). For a broader picture of what the general public might include in the category, you can for example browse the [ESPN Endurance Sports](http://espn.go.com/endurance/) feed or sites like [Endurance Sportswire](http://www.endurancesportswire.com/), which include coverage of triathlons and [Ironman](http://www.ironman.com/) competitions, marathons and other long-distance runs, and cycling among others.

Comment: I'm surprised the OP didn't find anything on Google. My Google search found 843,000 results, including Wikipedia, which says 'Endurance sports are a subset of sports in which the goal is prolonged athletic output over an extended distance or for an extended period of time', and includes a list of endurance sports in general, individual events and people (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Endurance_sports).

Answer (score 1):

It means the athletes who participant in activities such as marathon, tri-marathon, long-distance running as such

Comment: Longer distance obstacle racing (like the longer Spartan races) is another good example.